# ATmega328P presumably dead after probable SPI short circuit

Tags: avr, spi, short-circuit, avrdude

I am trying to use an ATmega328P to interface an SPI device (RFM95W radio module). This worked pretty well (I could measure the correct signals on SCK, MISO, MOSI and CS), but after some programming cycles (to test new versions of the firmware), avrdude complained about a

```
verification error, first mismatch at byte 0xyz
0xfoo != 0xbar
```

I encountered this error the next few times I frantically tried to flash the code (only the hexadecimal values changed randomly), and indeed, the error did vanish, but another one occurred. Now there was a device signature mismatch, and even adding the -F parameter or completely disconnecting the RFM95W couldn't convince avrdude to flash the code. The only thing that changed was the reported device signature; it seemed completely random. After some more tries, I gave up on the chip, removed it from the breadboard while leaving everything else in place and used an other ATmega328P I had lying around. Et voila: everything worked completely fine again without changing any settings in avrdude or altering the wiring. After that, I reconnected the RFM95W and still everything worked like a charm. But a few cycles later, the same problems occurred as with the previous chip, so I also gave up on that chip.

The only theory I can come up with is that there must have been some sort of short circuit, since both the programmer and the RFM95W use SPI to talk to the ATmega. This seems very likely, as the programmer resets the microcontroller before programming and emitting any SPI signals, so the ATmega should no longer act as a SPI master and stop talking on MOSI, SCK and CS, but the radio module keeps transmitting on MISO. Maybe they are just crosstalking, which leads to the programmer believing it has to flash with different parameters than actually required and doing so kills the chip.

Now, what I would like to know is:

1. whether there is a chance of reviving the ATmegas, and
2. how I can prevent this from happening in the future so that I don't kill a third ATmega.

Comment: You might want to post schematics to know what might be wrong.

Comment: It's very unlikely that what you damaged the ATmega hardware.  At the outside, maybe  you set a fuse oddly.  At bare minimum you are going to need to make sure that the radio's chip select is held high during ISP programming attempts; put an external pullup resistor there and measure that the signal is truly high.

Comment: Hopefully you also implemented proper voltage conversion between the radio and MCU, overvolting the radio could damage it, and could load the SPI signals to the point of unreliability.  If you are running your ATmega at 3v3 then hopefully you aren't trying to use a programmer with 5v I/O on it - doing that *could* damage the ATmega sooner or later.

Comment: Have you tried slowing the clock-rate on the programmer?  I have seen these same symptoms get resolved by running the programmer at a lower frequency.

Comment: @evildemonic Yes, I did. I usually flash at 125 kbaud/s, but I also tried various rates from 10 to 800kbaud/s.  I'm sorry I forgot to mention this in the question.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I didn't need a voltage conversion; I setted the programmer into a 3.3V mode and verified that it only emitted 3.3V signals on all relevant pins (MOSI, MISO SCK, CS, VCC) using an oscilloscope. Flashing the ATmega this way has always been working fine until I connected the RFM95W. I didn't modify any fuses except CLKDIV8 to leverage the full 8MHz provided by the internal oscillator. Thank you very much for your help!